# Codeigniter callback funtion in form Validation not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Import library

> ```
> $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
> $this->load->library('form_validation');
> ```

Set rules

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('START_DAY', 'lang:START_DAY', 'callback_start_check|required');
```

Callback Function

```
public function start_check($startdate){
....
}
```

It's all in one controller.

My `required` validation is working but my form validation don't run on my callback function. I saw many thread about that but there are just something about changing MY_Form_validation.php. However, I really want to know how my code is not working ?

I found that in Form_validation.php, method `method_exists($this->CI, $rule)`return FALSE with $rule is exactly my function name. So problems may come from `$this-CI`. However, it's point to exactly my controller path. What's wrong with that ?

Comment: how to debug code, did you try `die($startdate)` in callback function?

Comment: Yes, but it not run into my callback function at all

Answer (score 0):

Change the sequence of rules:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('START_DAY', 'lang:START_DAY', 'required|callback_start_check');
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you -

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','required|callback__unique_name[Role.name]');
//double underscore after callback
```

And this would be callback function -

```
public function _unique_name($name) {
     //Put your validation code here
}
```